# Xgboost binary format spec

Tags: java, parsing, machine-learning, prediction, xgboost

I am trying to implement a parser (in java) for xgboost gradient boosted tree but I am unable to find any binary spec or format. I did look up xgboost4j xgboost-predictor-java and xgboost-jpmml library and all of them parse the binary model , but it is hard to reverse engineer from the code , wondering if anyone can give pointers .

Comment: I don't think there's an official one. Have you considered using model dump, e.g. as JSON?

Comment: yes , i do have parser for text format (which actually has bugs , the text format produced has some errors compared to binary model) , and i do have parser for the pmml format produced by jpmml. I want the binary spec because , then i don't need to worry additional dependencies about pmml produced by jpmml library (hence not worrying about any pmml specific stuff and bugs ) , same for text.

Comment: Could you submit bugs in the text format to https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost?

Comment: https://github.com/KOLANICH/kaitai_struct_formats/blob/xgboost/scientific/data_science/dmlc/xgboost/xgboost.ksy may be what you want